# ASP.NET MVC 3 and Custom Resource Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, globalization

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. In this application I need to fetch localized strings from a database. So I am  writing a custom resource provider using the technique described in this article http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx.

Question 1: I would like to know how to specify the localized strings in the views. If the localized strings are from a resource file, they would be specified as @{Namespace}.{ResourceFileName}.{ResourceKey} as mentioned in http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx. How would the localized strings be specified in my case where the strings are in a database.

Question 2: Also I need to create custom resource provider factory class derived from ResourceProviderFactory. Here i have to override the CreateLocalResourceProvider method which takes one parameter "virtualpath". I would like to know to what value would be passed to the “virtualpath” parameter when the CreateLocalResourceProvider is called. Is there a way to control  through code the value passed to the “virtualpath” parameter.

Answer (score 1):

once i decided it like below
(for aspx view engine)

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Create")%>">
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UI.MyType, CreateNew %>" />
</a>
```

maybe it help